# Scraping a youtube page returns empty list

Tags: python, youtube, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I've been trying to scrape links from this youtube page. . But, the links variable comes up empty. Anything I am doing wrong?? [image: I have attached the code with this question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies with the way you are trying to find the links. When I `curl` the same url as you `curl https://www.youtube.com/results\?search_query\=hello`

I don't get any `a` tags with those css elements on it. This seems based on the `User-Agent` property set in the header.

So there are a few options:

1. Change how you look for the video link.

   This is what video links markup looks like for my curl

   ```
   <a href="/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A" class="yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link " data-sessionlink="itct=CFcQ3DAYASITCLfbt4P439gCFQzYfgodkDYKVij0JFIFaGVsbG8" title="Adele - Hello" aria-describedby="description-id-484065" rel="spf-prefetch" dir="ltr">Adele - Hello</a>
   ```

   As you can see those classes do not exist here.

   However you can use some sort of regular expression on the hrefs to find ones that contain the correct format

   ```
   page.find_all("a", {'href': re.compile('/watch?v=[A-Za-z0-9_\-]`)})
   ```

   (you will have to mess with the regex it isn't perfect
2. Use the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

   I would say this would be the preferred method just guessing what you are trying to do. Specifically the [search api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) they even have python snippets

Comment: Thank you. I got the class included in the code by "inspecting" the page, which is probably visible in the bottom half of my original picture. Is there something wrong with doing that? Also can you please tell me how you obtained those video links markup?

Comment: @beebeckzzz I just ran a curl on the url you had in your screenshot `curl https://www.youtube.com/results\?search_query\=hello`